# Unity 5.3 with C# - Toggle Sound On/Off

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine

*I'm working with Unity 5.3 with C# as code editor*

**These are what I have :**

I have 2 scenes in my project : `home` and `options`. I have `bg` object on both scenes. Both `bg` objects have `Audio Source` component, which contains same background music that `play on awake`. I don't use any codes for these background musics, I only click the `Add Component` button from Unity and add `Audio Source`.

**This is what I want :**

`Options` scene can toggle the background music on/off for all scenes. Therefore, there are `btnOn` and `btnOff` in `Options` scene.

**This is my code in Audio Manager.cs :**

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class AudioManager : MonoBehaviour {
    public Button btnOn;
    public Button btnOff;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        btnOn = GetComponent<Button>();
        btnOff = GetComponent<Button>();

        btnOn.onClick.AddListener(() => PlayAudio());
        btnOff.onClick.AddListener(() => StopAudio());
    }

    void PlayAudio()
    {
        AudioSource.volume = 0.5f;
    }

    void StopAudio()
    {
        AudioSource.volume = 0f;
    }
}
```

**This is the problem :**

I have this error : `An object reference is required to access non-static member UnityEngine.AudioSource.volume`. Maybe, this is because I don't write `public AudioSource audioSource` in my code. But, if I write this, I have to add another audio in `Get Component` box, and I will have double `Audio Source` in one scene. What should I do? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As you have a `bg` object in both scenes and as your `AudioManager` isn't marked as `[DontDestroyOnLoad]` (then I assume you also have one `AudioManager` in both scenes), it's `Start()` function will fire each time you load a scene.

So you can declare a `private AudioSource` and get a reference of it by finding your bg object in your scene and calling `GetComponent` on it :

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class AudioManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Button btnOn;
    public Button btnOff;

    private AudioSource audioSource;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        btnOn = GetComponent<Button>();
        btnOff = GetComponent<Button>();

        btnOn.onClick.AddListener(() => PlayAudio());
        btnOff.onClick.AddListener(() => StopAudio());

        audioSource = GameObject.Find("bg").GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }

    void PlayAudio()
    {
        audioSource.volume = 0.5f;
    }

    void StopAudio()
    {
        audioSource.volume = 0f;
    }
}
```

Comment: It has this error: `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of object`

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the hierarchy of your scene ?

Comment: You can see it [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bainn1z8wd1ft1w/Capture.JPG?dl=0)

Comment: When using GameObject.Find(), you have to specify the **exact** name of the object, so in your case `audioSource = GameObject.Find("BG_Options").GetComponent<AudioSource>();`. If you don't want to depend on the name of the object, you can use `audioSource = FindObjectOfType<AudioSource>();`.

Comment: I have tried both ways, but they still have the same error like before

Comment: I didn't pay attention at first look but as your `AudioManager` component and your `AudioSource` component are on the same object, you should be able to just do `audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130682/discussion-between-grace-michelle-and-whatever).

Comment: If you're interested I made a simple project and everything works fine : https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8i7bJozxe5BTm1HZ3lpZlFPcEk Maybe it will help you finding the issue on your side !

Comment: Thanks, I will try it

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't open your file, because you use a higher version Unity

Comment: Made the same one with Unity 5.3.5f1 : https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8i7bJozxe5BdXRiSnBkMEFKQ3c

Comment: Your code is still not working as I want, but because you had tried to help me, I'll upvote you. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The error is raised because you need to assign the property on an individual object; the volume is not shared between sources. For this reason you will either need a field to assign in the inspector, or get a reference with `GetComponent`.

While using different scenes for handling options is not wrong, it is a tad clumsy; the current scene has to be unloaded (destroying all object not marked as `DontDestroyOnLoad` and information associated with them), after which the options are loaded, to then load the previous scene. While unloading the music most likely stops playing, which, after loading, starts at the beginning again. Not mention any settings on these objects are lost (volume, change of track, etc.).

The afore mentioned `DontDestroyOnLoad` can help since you make your changes on the same object, but you will have to deal with duplicates each time a scene is loaded where such an object exists... you can use the function [`OnLevelWasLoaded`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnLevelWasLoaded.html) (documentation is a tad lacking at the moment) as a moment to determine which objects to destroy.

Another point is that you currently have public `Button` fields. This allows the for the assignment of them via the inspector, but that is rather moot as you overwrite them in `Start` (new value being the first button component assigned to the same object). I would make these fields private, or at least make sure they are not assigned. But I'm getting slightly of topic on how to keep settings persistent between scenes.

Here is some code to give you an idea, but be warned it is untested as I currently have no access to an environment to test it. This solution uses an object which is persistent between scenes. Keep in mind that any connections established to this object via the editor are lost after another scene has loaded.

```cs
public class AudioManager : MonoBehaviour
{
  private AudioSource source;

  // Called regardless of whether the object is enabled or not.
  // Should not be called in a new scene.
  private void Awake()
  {
    // Protect this object from being destroyed so its volume
    // is maintained between scenes.
    DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
    source = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
  }    

  public void DestroyPossibleDuplicates()
  {
    AudioManager[] managers = FindObjectsOfType(typeof(AudioManager)) as AudioManager[];
    foreach (AudioManager manager in managers)
    {
      // Use something to determine whether a manager is a duplicate.
      // It must not be this, but have something in common; a name perhaps?
      if ((manager != this) && (manager.gameObject.name == this.gameObject.name))
      {
        // Destroy the duplicates so their sound won't interfere.
        Destroy(manager.gameObject);
      }
    }
  }

  private void BindToInterface()
  {
    Slider[] sliders = FindObjectsOfType(typeof(Slider)) as Slider[];
    foreach (Slider slider in sliders)
    {
      // Determine whether the specified slider should have effect on this object.
      // If the slider's name contains this object's name assume it should.
      if (slider.gameObject.name.indexOf(this.gameObject.name)!=-1)
      {
        slider.onValueChanged.addListener((float value)=>
        {
          // In this case a slider is used for more control over the volume.
          // Different elements require other logic to function.
          source.volume = value;
        });
      }
    }
  }

  // If my memory serves correct this method is only called on objects 
  // that were in the scene before it started loading.
  // Just to be safe, don't have it do anything depending on this difference.
  private void OnLevelWasLoaded()
  {
    DestroyPossibleDuplicates();
    BindToInterface();
  }     
}
```

Comment: It has this error: `Type string does not contain a definition for indexOf and no extension method indexOf of type string could be found`

Comment: Lately been using some other programming languages which uses function names starting with lowercase. `IndexOf` should do the trick. `Contains` should also work (as that was actually intended; forgot C# had it).

Comment: The code from you has two errors. That's the first one. This is the second one: `Type UnityEngine.UI.Slider.SliderEvent does not contain a definition for addListener and no extension method addListener of type UnityEngine.UI.Slider.SliderEvent`

Comment: I wardned that it is untested code. In any case same problem as before (lowercase function name). `AddListener`. 

Another point is (as you might have noticed) this code expects a slider with a name that contains the name of the object this script is attached to. If it is not available it won't bind to its events.

Comment: I don't have slider in my project. Should I make one and put `AudioManager` script there?

Comment: Not required, but you will need to add the listener to another event (`onClick` for a button, `onValueChanged` for a toggle, etc.), not to mention a different way to determine what volume should be assigned.

This is quite easy in case of a slider, and gives a lot of control to the user; hence I chose it.